# subtract pairs of rows for long dataset

Tags: r, subtraction

I would like to find a way to subtract in a long dataset, both time and meters values every two rows (two measures per day) and therefore create a new table that store those values.
(03:21-09:37 and 3.2-0.9, so on...). Is there a function that can do it automatically. how is possible to set it? I am completly new using R and I need to figure out those things only with R

```
time <- c("03:21","09:37","15:41","21:46","03:54","10:12")
day <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2)
meters <- c(3.2,0.9,3.2,0.9,3.2,0.9)

df <- data.frame(day,time,meters)

  day  time meters
1   1 03:21    3.2
2   1 09:37    0.9
3   1 15:41    3.2
4   1 21:46    0.9
5   2 03:54    3.2
6   2 10:12    0.9
```

Comment: Not exactly clear. What do you mean "03:21-09:37 and 3.2-0.9, so on..."? Can you post your desired output for this small dataset? You mention "two measures per day", but "day == 1" has 4 measures.

Comment: yes there are 4 measures per day because they corresponds to two periods of tide. first value high tide second low tide third hoght tide and fourth low tide each day. I want to subtract high and low tide every 6 hours. would be great to find a way to subtract couple of rows. the first with the second, the third with the forth, the fifth with the sixth and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of options that quickly come to mind to consider:

***Option 1***: Subset with `TRUE` and `FALSE` to calculate the difference:

```
Time <- strptime(df$time, format="%H:%M")
TimeD <- Time[c(TRUE, FALSE)] - Time[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
MetersD <- df$meters[c(TRUE, FALSE)] - df$meters[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
cbind(meters = MetersD, time = TimeD)
#      meters      time
# [1,]    2.3 -6.266667
# [2,]    2.3 -6.083333
# [3,]    2.3 -6.300000
```

***Option 2***: Use `%/%` to create a grouping variable and use `aggregate`

```
df$pairs <- c(0, 1:(nrow(df)-1) %/% 2)
df$time2 <- strptime(df$time, format="%H:%M")
aggregate(list(meters = df$meters, time = df$time2), 
          by = list(pairs = df$pairs), FUN=function(y) diff(rev(y)))
#   pairs meters       time
# 1     0    2.3 -6.266667 
# 2     1    2.3 -6.083333 
# 3     2    2.3 -6.300000
```

---

#### Update

It's not too difficult to extend the idea to get your "day" column back tooL

```
with(df, {
  time <- strptime(time, format="%H:%M")
  time <- time[c(TRUE, FALSE)] - time[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
  meters <- meters[c(TRUE, FALSE)] - meters[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
  day <- day[c(TRUE, FALSE)]
  data.frame(day, time, meters)
})
#   day            time meters
# 1   1 -6.266667 hours    2.3
# 2   1 -6.083333 hours    2.3
# 3   2 -6.300000 hours    2.3
```

Comment: I think result should have 5 rows, as per Brandon's answer.

Comment: @BrodieG, what makes you think so? I don't get that impression from the description or the comment.

Comment: @BrodieG My initial thought too. It's not really clear.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, you forgot to edit my results :-) Now my answer looks wrong with the example data you've edited into the OP's question!

Comment: haha, sorry Ananda! I'll update again. But really, I was trying to steal your votes!

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, no problem--already taken care of. And I had donated a vote to you a while back. Hopefully BrodieG drops by and gives you their vote back too...

Comment: Sorry guys, I still need some help. I would like to keep the column relative to the day when I use the option 1 provided by @Ananda.the first 4 rows are in fact relative to day 1, the last two rows to day 2. I would like to have the three rows of the result with also the column of the day. is it possible?At the end the new database should have the three columns: day, meters, time and 3 rows. Do you think is it possible?Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `diff`

```
# Create a proper date
df$date <- strptime(paste(df$day,df$time),format="%d %H:%M")

new_df <- data.frame(
  diff_meters = abs(diff(df$meters)), 
  diff_time = diff(df$date))

new_df

      diff_meters      diff_time
1         2.3 6.266667 hours
2         2.3 6.066667 hours
3         2.3 6.083333 hours
4         2.3 6.133333 hours
5         2.3 6.300000 hours
```

It's pretty easy to get every other row, if that's what you're actually looking for (not really clear from the question nor your comment:

```
new_df[seq(1,nrow(new_df),2),]

  diff_meters      diff_time
1         2.3 6.266667 hours
3         2.3 6.083333 hours
5         2.3 6.300000 hours
```